# Node module not fully loading into browser

Tags: jss

I am building a custom component library using Stenciljs and webcomponents. I have published to an npm repo and was able to create an example create-react-app app using all of the components without an issue. However, when pulling the library into a jss/sitecore app the npm package is never fully loaded in the browser.

`staticjs/<localpath>/nodemodules/g-component-library/dist` I only see the `index.mjs` file.

I'm wondering if webpack is responsible but I'm not sure why it doesn't have issues with any other package. I'm not even sure which code would be relevant since there are a lot of moving parts but this is the react component we are trying to consume our custom component in.

```
import React from "react";
import "./footer.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "g-component-library";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Footer(props) {
  // const { handleNext } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={
        props.pageStyle === "full"
          ? "footer-container-full"
          : "footer-container"
      }
    >
      <div
        className={
          props.pageStyle === "full" ? "footer-buttons-full" : "footer-buttons"
        }
      >
        <input
          id="cancel"
          type="button"
          value={props.backButtonLabel || "Cancel"}
        />
        <input
          id="next"
          type="button"
          onClick={props.handleNext}
          value={props.nextButtonLabel || "Next"}
        />
        <g-button id={'test'} type={'primary'}>G Button</g-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Footer.propTypes = {
  handleNext: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you this?

https://stenciljs.com/docs/react

After dropping that to `src/index.js` it worked fine.
Did not need to do 'import "g-component-library";' , since the script below adds custom tags.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// test-component is the name of our made up Web Component that we have
// published to npm:
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'test-components/loader';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements();
});
```